# How to stop 'beginupdate' event in BufferedStore?

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to stop the event in beginupdate Ext.data.BufferedStore:

```
    Ext.define('BufferedStoreGrid', {
extend: 'Ext.data.BufferedStore',
xtype: 'BufferedStoreGrid',
storeId: 'Store',
pageSize: Constants.countRowGrid,
model: "ComboModel",
leadingBufferZone: false,
trailingBufferZone: false,
autoLoad: false,
proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    reader: {
        rootProperty: 'data'
    }
}
, listeners: {
    beginupdate: function (eOpts) {
        console.log('beginupdate');
        if (this.proxy.reader.rawData) {
            if (this.proxy.reader.rawData.data) {
                if (this.proxy.reader.rawData.data.length === 0) {
                    return false; // <-- this freeze grid
                }
            }
        }
    }
}});
```

while grid freeze.
how to do it correctly?

Comment: According to the docs http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.BufferedStore-event-beginupdate you cannot prevent the operation at this point.  What is the result you are trying to get?

Comment: Don't touch this, you'll break the grid.